# An EJB is in a JAR but is not found by the WAR next to in in an EAR

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I have the structure described below, but I cannot make it so `MyWebService` has its member `myService` not null. The code of `MyWebService` is properly executed when I call the webservice. When I look at the JBoss logs, I keep seeing that `MyServiceBean` has several JNDI bindings allocated to it.

So how do I bind `MyServiceBean` to `MyWebService`?

Thanks!

my-ejb.jar:

```
@Local
public interface MyServiceBeanLocal {
  ...
}

@Stateless
public class MyServiceBean implements MyServiceBeanLocal {
  ...
}
```

my-web.war:

```
@Webservice(...)
public class MyWebService {
  @EJB
  MyServiceBeanLocal myService;
  ...
}
```

my-ear.ear:

```
* my-ear.ear
|-* my-web.war
|-* my-ejb.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CXF. CXF is not an EJB container, hence the issues I got.

I had to manually bind the EJBs, using their full name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `MyServiceBeanLocal` as a Remote interface ? You are trying to use dependency injection from a Web module and for a Local Interface .This is not actually suggested. Anyway, At first try to make the interface `@Remote` . If still it doesn't work try to use`Remote Look up from the Web module for your Remote interface [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project?_sscc=t)

Comment: Why would I use Remote ? They all are deployed on the same JVM. Gonna try this tomorrow, thanks!